# How do I create an everybody list of statuses?

Tags: 7

I'm implementing a Facebook/Yammer like front page, and I have downloaded and installed the [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://drupal.org/project/statuses) module.
This works well, but for the life of me I can't get the status block to work as I would like. Can anyone help?

All I need is a status page as front page, where everyone can post and see those posts.

I have the latest release of the module for Drupal 7 (7.x-1.0-beta1), the Flags, Views and [Facebook-style Statuses Tag Suggestions](http://drupal.org/project/fbssts) modules installed.

Comment: Without having used the statuses module, I think this question looks borderline "too localized". If it could be re-written so it's not such an exact fit to your site only, it would be much better.